# Download files in the ajax success call

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I wanted to download a file in the ajax success call with out opening in a new tab/window.

File types would contain images(jpg, png) and all other doc extensions like doc, docx, pdf, ppt, pptx etc

Tried options with window.open and it is always opening in a new window.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url",
    success: function(result) {
       window.open(download_url);
});
```

Comment: I think you should look here for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

change `download_url` to the appropriate image link, and `img.png` to the image you want it to be called when being downloaded

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "url",
    success: function(result) {
       var a = $("<a>");
       a.attr("href", download_url).attr("download", "img.png").appendTo("body");
       a[0].click();    
       a.remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it to open in the same window like this

```
window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")
```

**_self** here specifies that it should be opened in same window.